# Know relative all child images are loaded using universal-image-loader library

Tags: java, android, image, android-recyclerview

Here my problem is I am preparing an image using a list of images I don't want to show the image until all the images loading completed. I am using maintaining image count it will be updated after image load complete. but if I am scrolling RecyclerView then images showing before all images loading.

```
 for(int i=0;i<mlist.getPosts().get(position).getOrderedDetails().size();i++){
            final ImageView imageView=new ImageView(activity);
            ImageAware imageAware = new ImageViewAware(imageView, false);
            final int finalPosition5 = position;
            holder.postrelative.addView(imageView);
            etOrderedDetails().get(i).getColorCode()));
            imageView.setLayoutParams(holder.postrelative.getLayoutParams());
            imageLoader.displayImage(mlist.getPosts().get(position).getOrderedDetails().get(i).getImage(), imageAware,options, new ImageLoadingListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {

                    for(int i=0;i<Constants1.imagecount.size();i++){
                        Log.d("loadedimages12",position+",,,"+i+",,,"+Constants1.imagecount.get(i)+",,,"+mlist.getPosts().get(i).getImagecount()+",,,"+mlist.getPosts().get(i).getOrderedDetails().size());

                    }
                    if(Constants1.imagecount.size()<=position)
                        Constants1.imagecount.add(1);
                    else
                        Constants1.imagecount.set(position,Constants1.imagecount.get(position)+1);
                    Log.d("imagecompleted",position+",,,,"+ Constants1.imagecount.size()+",,,,"+mlist.getPosts().get(position).getOrderedDetails().size());
                    mlist.getPosts().get(position).setImagecount(mlist.getPosts().get(position).getImagecount()+1);
                    if(Constants1.imagecount.get(position)==mlist.getPosts().get(position).getOrderedDetails().size()+1){
                        holder.imageloading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        mlist.getPosts().get(position).setImagecount(0);
                        Constants1.imagecount.set(position,0);
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Hi, please provide a working example of whatever you have already tried. Please see : http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: its my source code review please